# UnicodeDecodeError (UTF-8) for JSON

Tags: python

**BLUF:** Why is the `decode()` method on a `bytes` object failing to decode `ç`?

I am receiving a `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode by 0xe7 in position....`. Upon tracking down the character, it is the `ç` character. So when I get to reading the response from the server:

```
conn = http.client.HTTPConnection(host = 'something.com')
conn.request('GET', url = '/some/json')
resp = conn.getresponse()
content = resp.read().decode() # throws error
```

I am unable to get the content. If I just do `content = resp.read()` it is successful, I can write to file using `wb` but then whever the `ç` is, it is replaced with `0xE7` in the file upon writing. Even if I open the file in Notepad++ and set the encoding to UTF-8, the character only shows as the hex version.

Why am I not able to decode this UTF-8 character from an HTTPResponse? Am I not correctly writing it to file either?

Comment: Have you considered using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)?

Comment: @kichik No need. `requests` is just a high level API for making the same type of requests. It relies on `http.client` to make the socket connections anyhow. The example I have shown is somewhat false, as I am really making HTTPS connections and `requests` does not support SSL.

Comment: @kichik Further, the real question is _why does `decode()` not work on a valid UTF-8 character?_

Comment: The server doesn't seem to send you actual UTF-8. I was hoping requests will do better at detecting that. The actual UTF-8 representation for `ç` is `b'\xc3\xa7'`. The server is sending you CP1252.

Comment: @kichik How do you know it is CP1252 and not ISO-8859-1?

Comment: I don't. I have to guess based on the information I have. Both encode `ç` as `\xe7`. The server should tell you what it uses with `Content-Type` and I would expect a decent Python library to use that header.

Comment: What does `resp.getheaders()` return?

Comment: @MarkRansom I tried that...surprisingly its empty...

Comment: CP1252 is a superset of ISO-8859-1, and on web pages the two are often used interchangeably even though they aren't strictly identical.

Comment: @MarkRansom So I got the headers, but nothing about encoding other than `('Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked')`. The `Content-Type` is `application/json`.

Comment: @datta `requests` does support ssl.  Additionally it provides decoded content through the `response.text` attribute as well as the `response.encoding` attribute for the encoding that was guessed.

Comment: @MarkRansom RFC 2616 states that the default charset is `ISO-8859-1` if the `Content-Type` is `text` and there is no explicit charset in the headers.  Although I'm not certain if there is a similar restriction for `application/json`.

Comment: @BrianM.Sheldon My mistake, it has to do with my cert/key combo. They are encrypted and there is no support for that as per the [docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#client-side-certificates).

Comment: The techniques for determining the source encoding are rather involved: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#determining-the-character-encoding. This is why everyone suggests using a library like `requests` to do it for you. If you want to do it yourself that link should give you enough rope to hang yourself.

Comment: @MarkRansom Thanks, as I commented before, `requests` is great, but cannot handle encrypted SSL certs so I have to make the lower level socket connections myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have issues with encoding/decoding, you should take a look at the [UTF-8 Encoding Debugging Chart](http://i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html).

If you look in the chart for the `Windows 1252` code point `0xE7` you find the expected character is `ç` showing that the encoding is `CP1252`.